# include_path with environment variables like ${USER} and ${LOGIN} doesn't work

Tags: php, include-path

I'm trying to understand this.

I got this directory tree on my CentOS VM:

```
/home/  
   |_user1/ 
        |_classes/
        |_includes/
        |_public_html/
/home/
   |_user2/
        |_classes/
        |_includes/
        |_public_html/
/home/
   |_user3/
        |_classes/
        |_includes/
        |_public_html/
```

As you can see, `user1, user2`, and `user3`, they all have the same directory tree.
If I set the `include_path` in my `php.ini` file as follows:

```
include_path = "/home/${USER}/classes/:/home/${USER}/includes/"
```

and then place my `file1.inc.php` inside **includes** and `class.MyClass.php` inside **classes**, respectively, and then `require_once`, or `include_once`, or whatever, nothing happens, but `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` blabla, error...

From [PHP's Manual on include paths](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path):

> ENV variables are also accessible in .ini files. As such it is possible to reference the home directory using ${LOGIN} and ${USER}.
>   Environment variables may vary between Server APIs as those environments may be different.

So...
Is my `php.ini` settings in the right way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd suggest that you set the path at runtime in your scripts: eg: `set_include_path("/home/${USER}/")` and then include the files `include "classes/filename.php"` etc

Comment: Thank you @RamRaider, your solution is ok, but I need to do it in the way that I've described.

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
include_path =.:/home/${USER}/classes/:/home/${USER}/includes/
```

You can find the same solution in PHP Manual also i.e. some Unix systems (i.e. PHP 5.1.6 on Centos 5.2) include_path in php.ini should NOT be quoted. Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Ok, have tried with set_include_path http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php it set your include path as per os.

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it from my `php.ini` :|

Comment: I have checked the php.ini from centos 6.6 and there is an example given for writing the include path (as per ex given in php.ini this should be)include_path = ".:/home/${USER}/classes/:/home/${USER}/includes/";